# Поиск символов из String для составления нового слова

Tags: java

Имеется предложение "семантика" **(s1)** - это набор символов, из которых нужно составить слово "мак" **(s2)**.

Реализовываю таким методом, чтобы брались символы по очереди **из s1 (String)** и вставлялись **в sb (StringBuffer)**. На выходе получится **новая строка sb.**

В условии while проверяется, когда содержимое строки sb будет таким же как и s2 (по сути "мак" равно "мак").

> Читал про индексный метод, про циклический инкремент паролей, смотрел
>   примеры, вот только реализовать свой код не получается. Пишу свой код.
>   Вот, что получилось.
>
> Пробовал реализовать это (когда даны просто три символа "АВС" и из них
>   нужно составить всевозможные комбинации), но не получается:
>
> получить символ "A";
>
> записать его в ячейку szPassword[0];
>
> затем получить следующий символ - "B";   также записать его вместо
>   "A";
>
> получить символ "C";
>
> записать его вместо "B";
>
> определить, что мы дошли до конца алфавита;
>
> взять заново первый символ "A"
>
> записать его в ячейку szPassword[0];
>
> проверить ячейку szPassword[1];
>
> если там ноль, то изменилась длина пароля, поэтому пишем туда символ
>   "A";
>
> если там НЕ ноль, то инкремент этого символа;
>
> и так далее...

Что в коде не так?

```
package com.company;

public class Main {
public static StringBuffer word(String s1, String s2){
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.setLength(s2.length());
    int cout = 0;

    while (!sb.toString().equals(s2)){
        for(int i = 0, k = 0; i < s1.length() & k < s2.length(); i++) {
            sb.setCharAt(k, s1.charAt(i));
            System.out.println(sb);
            if(i == s1.length() -1 ){
                i = 0;
                sb.setCharAt(k, s1.charAt(i));
                k++;

            }
        }
    }

    return sb;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String  s1 = "семантика",
            s2 = "мак";
    System.out.println("Суммарное количество возможных комбинаций:\n" + Math.pow(s1.length(),s2.length()));
    System.out.println("\nНовая строка:\n" +word(s1, s2));

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать цикл в цикле.
Первый цикл будет итерироваться столько раз, сколько букв в выходном слове (мак), вложенный цикл будет проходить по всем буквам входного слова(семантика).
Во вложенном цикле сделать проверку - подходит ли эта буква к той, что вам сейчас нужна, если да, то записываем эту букву в `sb` и останавливаем вложенный цикл.

Comment: Это банально. Смысл в том, что искомое слово может быть любым и поэтому в цикле не вариант проводить проверку. Это своеобразный брутфорс должен получиться